# LuaInterface: Access objects properties

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface

i'm using LuaInterface to register a getter for some objects i want to have available in Lua. E.G:

```
    public MyObject getObjAt(int index)
    {
        return _myObjects[index];
    }
```

my Lua file:

```
obj = getObjAt(3) 
print(obj.someProperty)    // Prints "someProperty"
print(obj.moooo)           // Prints "moooo"
print(obj:someMethod())    // Works fine, method is being executed
```

How exactly can i access the public object properties after returning them in Lua? Is that even possible or do i have to write getter for each object property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find this code useful in understanding how to access the properties:

```
class Lister
{
    public string ListObjectMembers(Object o)
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        ProxyType proxy = o as ProxyType;

        Type type = proxy != null ? proxy.UnderlyingSystemType : o.GetType();

        result.AppendLine("Type: " + type);

        result.AppendLine("Properties:");
        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
            result.AppendLine("   " + propertyInfo.Name);

        result.AppendLine("Methods:");
        foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in type.GetMethods())
            result.AppendLine("   " + methodInfo.Name);


        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

and register the function:

```
static Lister _lister = new Lister();
private static void Main() {
    Interpreter = new Lua();

    Interpreter.RegisterFunction("dump", _lister,
    _lister.GetType().GetMethod("ListObjectMembers"));
}
```

Then in Lua:

```
print(dump(getObjAt(3)))
```